# How to check if a string is a valid hour range

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I would like to check if any string is valid hour range (%H%M-%H%M format) like:

```
12:00-13:00  # that is valid
```

I have tried:

```
try:
    time.strptime('12:00-13:00','%H:%M-%H:%M')
    return True
except ValueError:
    return False
```

but it raises regex error:

```
error: redefinition of group name 'H' as group 3; was group 1 at position 47
```

Could you point me to way to resolve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `valid hour range`, can you be more explicit please

Comment: You can't parse one string to two times. Maybe try splitting on the `-` and parsing each half separately (and if there aren't two halves, you already know it's invalid).

Comment: Hi @maslak , you can split the string on `-` and parse datetime, check my answer below :)

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string on `-`, then check if the number of elements in the resultant list is `2`.
If they are, parse both datetimes independently, and return `True` or `False` based on whether you can parse both of them successfully.

```
import time

def func(s):

    #Split string on -
    times = s.split('-')

    #If number of elements are not two, return False
    if len(times) != 2:
        return False
    else:

        try:
            #Try to parse both datetimes independently, if you can, return True, otherwise return False
            time.strptime(times[0],'%H:%M')
            time.strptime(times[1], '%H:%M')
            return True
        except:
            return False


print(func('12:00-13:00'))
#True
print(func('12:00-25:00'))
#False
print(func('00:00-25:00'))
#False
print(func('12:00'))
#False
print(func('abcd-efgh'))
#False
print(func('12:00-efgh'))
#False
```

Answer (score 1):

below code should help you get a quick solution. 
Note: given package is having better handling of error/exceptions and datetime object conversion.

```
from datetimerange import DateTimeRange

try:
    time_range = DateTimeRange("12:00", "23:00")
    print(time_range)
except ValueError as error:
    print(error)
```